# How to join 3 columns in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need [help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBmsB.jpg) for the script in how to join 3 columns in one using SQL. I want to join columns `address_1`, `address_2` and `address_3` in result window.

Comment: Join them in result window? What does that mean? You want them shown as 1 column?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your !

Comment: yes i want them shown in one column. here is my current script. select cust_code, cust_name, address_1, address_2, address_3, address_4, telephone
from a_customer order by cust_name asc  i want to join in 1 column the address_1, address_2, address_3, address_4

Comment: @LaposhasúAcsa my script is here now: select cust_code, cust_name, address_1, address_2, address_3, address_4, telephone
from a_customer order by cust_name asc

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for a `concat` operator as below.

```
SELECT cust_code,
       cust_name,
       address_1 + address_2 + address_3 + address_4,
       telephone
FROM a_customer
ORDER BY cust_name ASC;
```

You can check the demo [here](http://rextester.com/HWPL91247)

Comment: Thank you brodie.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 cust_code, 
 cust_name, 
 address_1 + address_2 + address_3 AS full_address, 
 address_4, 
 telephone 
FROM
 a_customer 
ORDER BY
 cust_name ASC
```

See [string concatenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql) in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for this. You saved me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for a concat operator as below.

SELECT cust_code,
       cust_name,
       address_1 + address_2 + address_3 + address_4,
       telephone
FROM a_customer
ORDER BY cust_name ASC